# RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal

Tags: git, github, git-push

Thanks for looking into this, I have a remote repository setup on **GitHub** and already configured my local repository as well, but I happen to run into this error every time I try to push changes to the remote, the error is

> Total 198 (delta 88), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
> error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
> Everything up-to-date

command used to push changes, `git push origin master`, I did read some answers online that assume the problem with network, however I don't think that's the problem with the network and this has been continuously the case, for over a month now. I referred following link that didn't help much, [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597915/my-git-push-is-not-working-giving-error-rpc-failed-curl-18-transfer-closed-wi)

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Are you using a proxy or TLS MITM device, or, on Windows, an antivirus or firewall other than the default?

Comment: @bk2204 I use windows 10 and have default windows security.